# Performing an action on one view, and the action doing something on another view? Is this possible?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I have 2 views:

- OneViewController
- TwoViewController

TwoViewController has an IBAction which plays a sound. Once the user has pressed the button on TWoViewController I want a UILabel which will appear on OneViewController saying that the sound has been played.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What have you tried? What worked? What didn't? You have to be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is reference one viewController in the other one, that way you can call it's methods. Or you can simply create a delegate.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use [notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000043i).

In the action that plays a sound, post a notification to the default notification center that indicates the sound has played.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:"playSoundNotification"
                                                    object:self 
                                                  userInfo:nil];
```

When OneViewController is created, have it register for the notification.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(showPlayedLabel:)                                                 
                                             name:"playSoundNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

When it receives the notification -- in showPlayedLabel: -- display the UILabel.  Note that showPlayedLabel must follow the appropriate signature format.

```
- (void) showPlayedLabel:(NSNotification*) aNotification;
```